Request.post() требует наличие 'https://' хотя оно уже есть
Пишу телеграм бота для игр на сайте encounter и там нужно работать в их апи. Это моя первая практика с работой с запросами вообще т.к. раньше я кодил чисто спортивное програмирование на с++. КОРОЧЕ ГОВОРЯ у меня выдает ошибку requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant https://? хотя в коде уже добавил ее, а в телеграме ввожу адрес без https://

import requests
import telebot

domain = ''
login = ''
password = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    if(message.chat.type != 'group'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Этот бот предназначен для помощи при прохождении игры Encouneter.\nЧто бы использовать его функционал добавте его в группу")
    else :
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f"Для работы бота зарегестрируйте его командой /register")
@bot.message_handler(commands=['register'],chat_types=['group'] )
def domainenter(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Введите имя домена на которому будет проходить игра \nПример: https://moscow.en.cx')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message,loginenter)
def loginenter(message):
    domain = 'https://' + message.text + '/login/signin?json=1'
    print(domain)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Введите логин пользователя с чьего аккаунта будет играть бот')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, passwordenter)
def passwordenter(message):
    login = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Введите пароль от аккаунта')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message,postlogin)
def postlogin(message):
    password = message.text
    data = {'Login' : login,
            'Password' : password}
    response = requests.post(domain, data = data)
    print(response.text)

bot.polling(none_stop=True) 


domain = '' - вы нигде не меняете значение этой глобальной переменной, и её значение навсегда остаётся пустой строкой

А ещё мы теперь можем управлять вашим ботом, потому что вы показали нам токен

@andreymal. Вопрос, у вас всё хорошо? Нельзя управлять ботами без API-Token'а, это знает каждый нормальный человек, а все domain не изменяется потому, что запустив код вы забываете про вызов def-функций (это просто: нужно вписать название, указанное после слова def).

По коду я понял, что похоже имя message используется в качестве имени сервера. А по остальным функциям понятно, что эта переменная используется в качестве совсем не имени сайта (сервера). Поэтому, в def loginenter() следует в domain = ... после https:// следует поставить имя домена, как я понял, это - телеграм: telegram.org. Вроде работающий код (на моём компиляторе):
import requests
import telebot

domain = ''
login = ''
password = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    if(message.chat.type != 'group'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Этот бот предназначен для помощи при прохождении игры Encouneter.\nЧто бы использовать его функционал добавьте его в группу")
    else :
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f"Для работы бота зарегистрируйте его командой /register")
@bot.message_handler(commands=['register'],chat_types=['group'] )
def domainenter(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Введите имя домена на которому будет проходить игра \nПример: https://moscow.en.cx')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message,loginenter)
def loginenter(message):
    domain = 'https://telegram.org/login/signin?json=1&login=' + message.text + '/'
    print(domain)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Введите логин пользователя с чьего аккаунта будет играть бот')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, passwordenter)
def passwordenter(message):
    login = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Введите пароль от аккаунта')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message,postlogin)
def postlogin(message):
    password = message.text
    data = {'Login' : login,
            'Password' : password}
    response = requests.post(domain, data = data)
    print(response.text)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)```
Также, я чуть-чуть подправил небольшие ошибочки.
Надеюсь, помог!

